# Why are arguments used to pass in a inputted value from outside of function. Rather than asking for and storing input all in function itself?

Tags: c

Why are arguments used to pass in a input from user most of the time instead of using code like scanf in function itself.

It would just make code cleaner.

But i most of the time see people write prompts ask for input store it in variable and pass it in as argument outside of function even when they dont re use value later on in code.

Is it just habit of people who write complex code so most of the time its better idea to save input in separate variable and then pass it in rather than just use scanf in body of function?

Because other option of putting everything in function always seems easier to read you dont need arguments which add another layer of unnecessary complexity because whole sub problem is contained in one abstraction?

Comment: [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). An important part of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) design principles. Handle input in one function (which often isn't as trivial as a single `scanf` call), handle processing in another.

Comment: What if you want your function to get its input from something else? Seperation of concerns - have one thing for getting the input, one for doing something with it, and another for handling the result.

Comment: So far in your learning, you are working on small “toy” programs that just exercise pieces of programming. They are not complicated; the program just gets a few pieces of input, does something fairly simple with them, and produces output. When people work on “real world” programs, they are much larger and much more complicated. Many inputs are collected from a user at one time, stored in a database, and used for calculations later. All the parts become more complex, and it becomes more important to separate them to keep the parts clean and free of interactions with other parts.

Comment: For example, good input software becomes fairly complicated in itself. It does not just read strings of characters that have been processed by a terminal program. It is graphic user interface (GUI) software that receives information about keystrokes typed by the user, validates the keystrokes and the data it represents, and guides the user when errors occur. This involves multiple layers of software just within the input software—things handling keystrokes, things handling mouse clicks, things handling forms, things handling drop-down boxes or text input fields, and more.

Answer (score 1):

It is too have a better overview and re usability of the code, exactly like most functions do not allocate their own memory and ask for a buffer instead.

Let us look at an examples.:

```
void reverse(const char* input, char* output, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        output[len - 1 - i] = input[i];
    }
    output[len] = 0;
}

int main() {
    char* my_input = malloc(MAX_INPUT_SIZE + 1);
    int len = read(1, my_input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE);
    if (len < 0) exit(1);
    char* my_output = malloc(len + 1);
    reverse(my_input, my_output, len);
    free(my_input);
    printf("%s", my_output);
    free(my_output);
}
```

If we look at the main function the programs control flow is very clear. We can see where memory is allocated and where it is freed. But most importantly, we can change the input method, without having to touch the `reverse()` function. If reverse would be a very complicated function, this would be pretty hard to do.
Let us look at an examples.:

```
char* reverse() {
    char* input = malloc(MAX_INPUT_SIZE + 1);
    int len = read(1, input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE);
    if (len < 0) exit(1);
    char* output = malloc(len + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        output[len - 1 - i] = input[i];
    }
    output[len] = 0;
    free(input);
    return output;
}

int main() {
    char* my_output = reverse();
    printf("%s", my_output);
    free(my_output);
}
```

As you can see, the calling method is a lot shorter. But the big drawback is, that we can't really see what reverse is doing on the first look. Now you would need to write a long comment (at least for a more complex function) what this does. Also we can not customize the memory allocation function, input function and error handling, without having to change `reverse`. And if we would use `reverse` in hundreds of places in our code, with slight differences in how they read input, you would have to write a new function for every of them.

Comment: Thanks, created this example while writing my answer, have not tested it

Comment: `len` is the argument provided. It has the lenght of the input byte array. `i` can be between 0 and `len - 1`, so `len - 1 - i` (or `len - i - 1`) is also always between 0 and `len - 1`. I think this should be correct. But yes, I see, I typed two times 1 (sorry, will edit).